# Constructor method takes constructor as parameter and returns constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object, methods, constructor

The method sum should take another vector as a parameter and return a new vector that has the sum of the two vectors(x and y values of **this** vector and the parameter). The return statement of sum gives an error, hence, `console.log(val3)` returns undefined. How do I fix this?

```
function Vector(a,b){
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
        this.sum = function(Vector){
            return Vector(this.x + Vector.x, this.y + Vector.y);
        }
    }
    Vector.prototype.show  = function(){
        document.write("x: "+this.x+" y: "+this.y);
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write("Distance from Origin: " + Math.sqrt((this.x)**2 + (this.y)**2).toFixed(2));
    }
    var val1 = new Vector(5,6);
    var val3 = val1.sum(val2);
    console.log(val3);
```

Comment: _"Uncaught ReferenceError: val2 is not defined"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `sum` argument a different name than `Vector` so that you can reference the outer `Vector` constructor:

```js
function Vector(a, b) {
  this.x = a;
  this.y = b;
  this.sum = function(otherVector) {
    return new Vector(this.x + otherVector.x, this.y + otherVector.y);
  }
}
var val1 = new Vector(5, 6);
var val2 = new Vector(-3, -3);
var val3 = val1.sum(val2);
console.log(val3.x, val3.y);
```

Comment: You didn't mention the lack of the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are instantiating a new object, you need to use the `new` keyword.

```js
new Vector(...)
```

Also, `val2` was never defined, so I changed `val3` to `val2`. Also, do not use `a` and `b` when they really mean `x` and `y`.

```js
function Vector(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.sum = function(other) {
    return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
  }
}
Vector.prototype.show = function() {
  document.write("x: " + this.x + " y: " + this.y);
  document.write("<br/>");
  document.write("Distance from Origin: " + Math.sqrt((this.x) ** 2 + (this.y) ** 2).toFixed(2));
}
var val1 = new Vector(5, 6);
var val2 = val1.sum(val1);
console.log(val2);
```

You could use ES5 classes instead.

I recommend you change `sum` to `add`, unless you are adding multiple vectors together. And avoid writing directly to the document, unless you are doing this inside of a frame.

```js
class Vector {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  add(other) {
    return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
  }
  distanceTo(other) {
    return Math.sqrt((this.x - other.x) ** 2 + (this.y - other.y) ** 2);
  }
  distanceFromOrigin() {
    return this.distanceTo(new Vector(0, 0)); // Could make (0, 0) a singleton
  }
  display(el) {
    const htmlText = `
      x: ${this.x}, y: ${this.y}
      <br />
      Distance from Origin: ${this.distanceFromOrigin().toFixed(2)}
    `;
    if (el === undefined) {
      const p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = htmlText;
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    } else {
      el.innerHTML = htmlText;
    }
  }
}
var val1 = new Vector(5, 6);
var val2 = val1.add(val1);
console.log(val2);
val2.display(document.querySelector('.info'));
```

```html
<div class="info"></div>
```